# How to download a file that redirects to another file?

Tags: curl, download

I want to be able to install all my apps on a new machine programmatically.

When I run

```
curl -o ~/Downloads/musescore.AppImage https://musescore.org/en/download/musescore-x86_64.AppImage
```

it downloads 25kb of nonsense. On the website the real file it redirects to in the browser is located at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/musescore/v4.1.1/MuseScore-4.1.1.232071203-x86_64.AppImage.

How do I get curl to get the correct file please?

I've already tried

```
curl -LO https://musescore.org/en/download/MuseScore-4.1.1.232071203-x86_64.AppImage
```

and

```
curl -o MuseScore.AppImage -LJ https://musescore.org/en/download
```

from chatgpt, but they didn't work.

Comment: The download link https://musescore.org/en/download/musescore-x86_64.AppImage redirects to `AppImage` file using `javascript`. The -L option in curl is for redirect response from server therefore it is not going to work here. I'm not sure if curl can handle js requests though.